# Wiring multiple beans with the same dependency via Spring Boot @Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection

In older Spring MVC apps, where you'd specify `application.xml` and declare your app's beans so that Spring DI could instantiate them and wire them together, you might have something like this:

```
<bean id="chargeFactory" class="com.example.myapp.ChargeFactory" />

<bean id="paymentService" class="com.example.myapp.DefaultPaymentService">
  <ref id="chargeFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="chargeAuditor" class="com.example.myapp.ChargeAuditor">
  <ref id="chargeFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Which might help wire up the following code:

```
public interface PaymentService {
    public void makePayment(Payment payment);
}

public class DefaultPaymentService implements PaymentService {
    @Autowired
    private ChargeFactory chargeFactory;

    @Override
    public void makePayment(Payment payment, String key) {
        Charge charge = chargeFactory.createCharge(key);
        charge.doCharge(payment);
    }
}

public class ChargeAuditor {
    @Autowired
    private ChargeFactory chargeFactory;

    public void auditAllCharges(String key) {
        List<Charge> charges = chargeFactory.getAllCharges(key);
        // blah whatever
    }
}
```

**How do you accomplish the same bean wiring in Spring Boot with the `@Configuration` class?** For example:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppInjector {
    @Bean
    public ChargeFactory chargeFactory() {
        return new ChargeFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public PaymentService paymentService() {
        return new DefaultPaymentService(chargeFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ChargeAuditor chargeAuditor() {
        return new ChargeAuditor(chargeFactory());
    }
}
```

This *might* work but introduces some issues:

1. It would force me to have to write value constructors for all my classes, which goes against everything I see in literally *every* tutorial/article I've come across. Plus, if I had to do that, then there's no real value to `@Autowired` anyways...
2. At this point I'm essentially doing "DIY DI", which is OK, except I'm trying to deliberately use Spring DI :-)
3. Every time I call `chargeFactory()` I'm getting a new (prototype-style) `ChargeFactory` instance. Maybe I want a singleton. Using this approach I have to hand-roll my own singleton implementation.

Sure, I *can* do all of this, but I feel like I'm flagrantly misusing/misunderstanding how `@Configuration` is supposed to be used, because it seems like I'm introducing a whole lot of DIY/homegrown code to solve something Spring DI should be able to do for me.

How would I reference the `chargeFactory` bean and wire it into both the "provider methods" for the `paymentService` and `chargeAuditor` beans? Again, looking for the Java-based `@Configuration` solution instead of writing an XML document to define the wirings.

I found [this article](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/boot/spring-boot-configuration-tutorial/) which seems to be the only tutorial/documentation (surprisingly) on wiring Spring Boot apps via `@Configuration` (which leads me to believe there might be other/better methods...), but it does not address:

- How to specify singleton vs prototype bean instantiation patterns
- If multiple instances of a bean-class exist, how do I specify which instance gets wired into which dependency?
- How do I get around not defining value constructors for **all** my classes, and just let Spring/`@Autowired` inject fields automagically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call chargeFactory() , spring won't create new instance everytime. Give it a try and see. Same object will be returned. Anyways 
You can do something like this.

```
@Bean 
public PaymentService paymentService(ChargeFactory chargeFactory) { return new DefaultPaymentService(chargeFactory); }
```

Comment: Hmmm thanks @pvpkiran (+1) is this documented anywhere? What if I **do** want a prototype for `chargerFactory`? What if I have two different instances of `chargerFactory` beans that I want wired differently into different dependencies?

Comment: You can use @Scope in conjunction with Bean annotation . I think the documentation is pretty clear http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html

Comment: Meh, I think its bonkers in 2017 that someone has to go hunting through Spring Javadocs to see how a **major feature** works, but maybe that's just me. Thanks for this!